# How to compare a vector to a rotation in Godot 4.1?

Tags: mathematics, vector, godot-4, character-controller

### The Context

In Godot 4.1, I have a third-person character controller. It's a CharacterBody3D with a child Node3D called PlayerContent. The visual components of the character (model, etc.) are all children of PlayerContent.
To move the character, I've created a Vector3 called direction that gets the joystick input:

```
func get_input_direction():
  direction.x = Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right")
  direction.z = Input.get_axis("move_forward", "move_backward")
```

The player can be Z-targeting or moving freely. In the case of moving freely, I rotate PlayerContent to match the direction of movement (giving the illusion that the character is turning, even though the CharacterBody3D isn't). In the case of Z-targeting, I rotate PlayerContent towards the target.

In order to make **direction** relative to the camera, I rotate **direction** by the camera's rotation.

```
func player_direction_to_camera():
  get_input_direction()
  direction = direction.rotated(Vector3.UP, camera.rotation.y)
```

Lastly, I set the **velocity** variable that *move_and_slide()* uses to equal **direction**.

### The Question

I'd like to be able to tell which way **direction** is compared to the value the Vector2 is being rotated by. For example, if the player is moving *left* (relative to PlayerContent's rotation), I'd like to be able to specify the dodge type to be *left_dodge* (or something to that effect.) Or *forward_dodge*, or *backflip*, or anything like that.

I'm not very good at vector math, so I'd appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the issue... So, I'll give you three scenarios, hopefully I cover your case.

---

**First scenario**: You want to know which way is `camera.rotation.y` rotating.

For that you can `wrapf` it:

```
wrapf(camera.rotation.y, -PI, PI)
```

Then the sign will tell you which way it is rotating.

---

**Second scenario**: You want to compare `direction` to the orientation of `PlayerContent` (or some other object).

The forward direction of `PlayerContent` would be:

```
var target_direction := -PlayerContent.global_transform.basis.z
```

*If `PlayerContent` is not what you want, you can replace it with any other `Node3D` (e.g. the `Camera3D` or the `CharacterBody3D`).*

And wince we know the rotation uses `Vector3.UP` as axis, we can use it in `signed_angle_to`:

```
direction.signed_angle_to(target_direction, Vector3.UP)
```

And again, you can use the sign to discriminate.

---

**Scenario tree**: You a `Basis` (perhaps from a `Transform3D`, for example from the `Camera3D`) or a `Quaternion`, and you want to know which way it rotates.

You need a vector that you know to be perpendicular to the axis. In our case the axis is `Vector3.UP`, so we can use `Vector3.FORWARD`...

Then compared with it transformed version:

```
Vector3.FORWARD.signed_angle_to(r * Vector3.FORWARD, Vector3.UP)
```

*Where `r` is the `Basis` or `Quaternion`.*

And once more, the angle will tell you which way it rotated.

---

**Bonus**: If you need the `Transform3D` of something relative to something else you can do this:

```
var r := something_else.global_transform.affine_inverse() * something.global_transform
```

That will give you a `Transform3D` such that `something_else.global_transform* r` is `something.global_transform`. That is the transform needed to go from `something_else` to `something`, in other words, the transform of `something` relative to `something_else`.